# Optional found Nil in UITableViewCell.xib

Tags: swift, uitableview, class

I do not understand why I still get this:

> Thread 1: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

when I run my app.

The problem comes from a UITableViewCell and it occurs when I want to set the label of the UITableViewCell to a title which comes from an object of type Cella. It is clearly not nil, as clear in the picture, but when setting the label I get this. I made sure I set every class of the correct type, used the correct identifier and everything.

[image: Xcode with Error]

[class Cella](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5IHe.png)

[ViewController1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVyx4.png)

[ViewController2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAgrK.png)

Comment: I know what an optional is. My point is: the variable I’m treating is not nil, and I don’t see any way in which it could be in this context. I do not think it is a duplicate of the post above

Comment: How is `setCell` called, and what is `cellFormatTaken`? It may be `nil`.

Comment: Could `Cella.title` be a force unwrapped optional?

Comment: I've added three more screenshots of my files, I've been trying to look for the error, but no luck so far. Hope they're helpful.

Comment: `title` is `nil`, there is no other possibility.

Comment: Also, please don't post code as images. Post code as text.

Comment: I don't see you registering the cell nib anywhere.

Comment: To be clear, you are probably not registering your cell properly and the nib is not even loaded. That's why your outlets are nil and that's why you get a crash.

Comment: @Sulthan the data I want to display is simply hard coded, I do not think I need any nib as for now. Rather, have printed the value cellFormat.title that I want to assign to cellObject.title.text, and it is a string. But literally on the next line of code, it signals it as "nil".

Comment: @NiccolòDiana Nope, it crashes because the outlet to which you are trying to assign is `nil`. And it is `nil` because there is no nib registered for that table.